# can twitter bootstrap work in symfony2 without less referring directly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

If I just refer to bootstrap.css files in my base.html.twig, the styling of the page seems to partly work as there seems some styling, but a lot of styling is missing like the menu and jumbotron for instance has no styling.

What I'm wondering is this because bootstrap will only work with symfony 2 if using assetic and less ?

this is how I reference them

```
  <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="{{ asset ('css/bootstrap-responsive.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: not sure if its helpful for you but this did the trick for me: https://github.com/fkrauthan/FkrCssURLRewriteBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got it to work

```
  {% stylesheets
    'bundles/your/css/thirdparty/bootstrap.css'
    filter="cssrewrite" %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  {% endstylesheets %}

  {% javascripts
    '@YourBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/jquery.js'
    '@YourBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/bootstrap.js'
    '@YourBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: Always the overlooked catches me out, I had an the old version of bootstrap on the live server, version 3 on the test that's why wasn't showing some of the css Doh!